# issue with jakson json mapping a polymorphic and cyclic reference

Tags: java, javascript, json, jackson

So far I haven't been able to find people having a solution to this or having the same issue: I cannot submit code but would try to explain with a diagram and as clear as possible.

Class A points to abstract B. Concrete class C then points back to A. A and B have db generated ids and C,D and E inherit the id form B. The id on C,D,E is still unique among all of them.

[image]

It is obvious that @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference cannot be used in this case as B is polymorphic. This case is one limitation the annotations have.

I was trying to use @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true) in C (where it points to A) and it causes C to only have the Id of A as expected and there is no issue serialising it, but on de-serialisation it might throw the famous "**Could not resolve Object Id .... -- unresolved forward-reference?**".

Does someone have a solution to this or maybe seen an example somewhere that might be useful to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all I was able to solve this issue and not with any help from Jackson but with a  recursive format method and a recursive removeDuplicateNodes() methode.

- The format method will remove extra UI related information attached to each node(A,B,C,D,E).
- It also copies any Node A that is linked to any node C. In other word it expands the Node A on C. i.e. Node C will have full description of Node A on itself. And Node A will also have its own full description.

once done with the formatting then it is time to remove duplicate in a way that there is no forward referencing. So starting from the root Node then we will do the following:

- if node A has C on it which is pointing to A* then will replace the full description of A* with just its ID.
- if node A doesn't have C on it then we don't care.

What is happening is that first we expand all the Nodes to have full description not just the id. Then recursively replace full description by just the id for any A node that has been previously described on a C node.

Hope this helps others.